# double integral exponential region

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Hi I have to solve the following double integral.

$$\iint _{R} e^{x+3y}dA\: \:and \: \: R=\left \{ y=1, y=2, y=x, y=5-x \right \}
$$

this is my approach:

$$\iint _{R} e^{x+3y}dA = \int_{1}^{2} \int_{1}^{x}e^{x+3y}dydx+\int_{2}^{3}\int_{1}^{2}e^{x+3y}dydx+\int_{3}^{4}\int_{1}^{5-x}e^{x+3y}dydx
$$

Is this work correct? am I going in the right direction?

Comment: There should be inequalities rather than equalities in the definition of $R$. Otherwise, you're doing right!

Comment: I think I forgot to mention that the problem asks to calculate the volume of the region enclosed by the following lines.

Comment: Of course. But then you should not write $\int\int_R$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The setup is correct. It is clear that you started the right way, by drawing a careful picture.  And if you choose to integrate first with respect to $x$, you do have to consider three separate integrals.

But from that picture, one can see that it is **much easier** to integrate first with respect to $x$. So $x$ goes from $y$ to $5-y$, and then $y$ goes from $1$ to $2$. One calculation instead of three!